# Docker failed to build on Rails bundle Install rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I use `Docker for Windows` which I use to run a Image for a Rails(v5) App.

When I do `docker-compose build` I get this error. I don't known where to look to debug and/or resolve this.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev
RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client
RUN apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev imagemagick
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y git
#RUN npm install -g phantomjs

RUN gem update --system

RUN mkdir -p /MyImage
WORKDIR /MyImage
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm update
RUN npm install

COPY . /MyImage

CMD [ "foreman", "start" ]
```

Here is a log if my error:

```
Step 15/20 : RUN bundle install
 ---> Running in 4bf360b89cb7
The git source `git://github.com/acrogenesis/owlcarousel-rails.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
The git source `git://github.com/sinatra/sinatra.git` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching source index from https://rails-assets.org/
Fetching git://github.com/sinatra/sinatra.git
Fetching git://github.com/acrogenesis/owlcarousel-rails.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/..
Fetching rake 12.1.0
Installing rake 12.1.0
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/templates/Executable
An error occurred while installing rake (12.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '12.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  autonumeric-rails was resolved to 2.0.0.1, which depends on
    jquery-rails was resolved to 4.3.1, which depends on
      railties was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
        rake
ERROR: Service 'MyImage' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 5
```

But when I do `gem install rake -v '12.1.0'` directly into the shell of my container, everything install just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to install rake by yourself as described in the error message:

```
gem install rake -v '12.1.0'
```

To debug:

1. Comment out all lines in your `Dockerfile` starting from `RUN bundle install` and to end;
2. Then run `docker build -t test:0.0 .`;
3. To start interactive session: `docker run -it test:0.0 /bin/bash`;
4. Try to execute `gem install rake -v '12.1.0'` manually...

Comment: @JudgeProphet can you run `gem install rake -v '12.1.0'` first and then run `bundle install` again in the same session? Will error still occure?

Comment: By the way. Which version of `bundler` gem is installed in your image? The `gem update --system` command only updates system gems. So the `bundler` can be still outdated.

Comment: I mean if `gem install` runs fine, the problem is probably related to `bundler` itself.

Comment: I update my DockerFile to force a Bundler Install, and still got the same error

Comment: @JudgeProphet It sound crazy, but can you try to add or run manually: `RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/templates/Executable`? =)

Comment: Good idea, but after adding it I got, Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory @ io_fread -
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/templates/Executable

Comment: @JudgeProphet I think that something in bundler installation is broken. You could also:

* Try to use another ruby image (maybe not one with the `-slim` postfix in tag);

* Remove bundler and reinstall it completely;

Comment: Finally what I did, is delete all my images,  upgrade the Ruby image version as you seed.  Rebuild all images. And Bam! it's start working!  
Tx, for your support,  it's really appreciate Zino!